# How does "putExtra" work?

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm following along on this example:

http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html

If you Ctrl-F for this `putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT` it'll take you to a segment of code I'm unsure of. Further up in the app, they override `onActivityResult` and try to pull the image from this intent out of the activity result to display in the app, but when I was doing this the Intent arg in `onActivityResult` was null. I tried changing my `putExtra` to take `"data"` instead of `MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT` and suddenly it works perfectly.

Can anyone explain what this tutorial is trying to get me to do?

So basically, **the code in question:**

```
static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;

private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        // Create the File where the photo should go
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // Error occurred while creating the File
            ...
        }
        // Continue only if the File was successfully created
        if (photoFile != null) {
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                    Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        mImageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
    }
}
```

`Intent data` in `onActivityResult` is null, so it'd crash when i called `getExtras`. I changed `dispatchTakePictureIntent` to `putExtra("data", Uri.fromFile(photoFile));` and it works.

I'm just confused if this is a blunder on Google's part and made a mistake in their tutorial, or if I did something wrong / don't understand? Only reason I thought to make this change is because it uses the string `data` when it calls `extras.get("data")`. So I don't even understand my solution :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
putExtra("NameOfExtra", object)
```

so they are getting an extra named "data"  - the string is the NAME of the extra value that was previously put.

Comment: Can you just name it anything you want? At first I thought extras were like, optional parameters with particular names and you had to specify which ones you wanted. Now I think it's always 1 pre-determined set of values and you just name it whatever you want?

Comment: @sab669 If you are using extras internally, i.e. to pass data back and forth within your application, you can name them whatever you want. But if you use extras to pass data when starting activities or services that belong to other applications, you need to specify the names needed by that activity or service.

Comment: Giulio is correct so in your example you HAVE to use "data" because that is what the camera intent used to store the data.

Comment: @GiulioPiancastelli you should put that an answer to this question, since it answers both the intent and spirit of this question.

Comment: @cbrulak thanks for the suggestion, but it's fine with me as it is.